# how to round the decimals to the upper value

Tags: sql-server-2008, decimal, rounding, floor

i am using sql server 2008 procedure, i have total rows divide by per page, i want that if the results contains any decimal value it should be rounded to its upper value.

i used below:

```
SELECT FLOOR(@TOTAL / CAST(@PageSize AS FLOAT)) AS TOTALPAGES, @TOTAL AS TOTALROWS
```

where @total is the float, this does not work. i also tried below

```
SELECT ROUND(@TOTAL / CAST(@PageSize AS FLOAT),0) AS TOTALPAGES, @TOTAL AS TOTALROWS
```

This works only when the decimal is >= 5, else it does not take the upper value.

i want that if the results is 12.2 then it should return 13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`CEILING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)  function. Not `ROUND` or `FLOOR` as in your question.

Comment: In addition, you can do the following: floor(value+.5).  Prefer the Ceiling function, just placing this as an FYI more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

If u have any decimal values it should be rounded to its upper value use CELLING or else use Round it give the accurate values.

```
Example for CEILING:
SELECT CEILING($123.45), CEILING($-123.45), CEILING($0.0) or
select CEILING(1.12) it takes 2

Example for ROUND:
But in Round see
select round(1.12,1) it takes as 1.10.
select round(1.15,1) it takes as 1.20.
```

Hope it will clear your doubts